# Two player iPad app - which player touched the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Is it theoretically possible to detect which player is touching the screen in two player iOS game? Let's say it's a board game with chess-like playfield and figures. If we used the front camera, could we use some kind of computer vision to detect a hand over the screen of the player "opposite" the screen?

Comment: In theory yes, in practice I dont think so.

Comment: do want the players touching the screen at the same time or are they taking turns?

Comment: Maybe soon: http://www.cnn.com/2013/06/27/tech/mobile/ios-7-motion-detection/

Comment: You could force player to put its finger in a particular position after touching the screen (i.e. he must keep a button pressed while not making a move), so you always know which player is moving. You could detect movement with the camera, but I think it would be too inaccurate to just relay on it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Especially since this is all theoretical. Let's think about this...

**Assumptions:**

You tagged this question with iPad, so I assume you mean on such a device.

We will assume the device is played with vertically, meaning the Camera is closest to a particular player, they are not equally spaced.

We assume users don't switch position at any point.

The game is chess.

**Process:**

We can do a few things to determine with a fairly high level of accuracy that a certain user tapped the screen.

**Step 1**

Since the camera is on one side of the device, we can continuously record through the camera, and programmatically remove a large portion of the outer borders of the recording, and wait for a change in the environment.

Then if the person on the side of the camera moves their hand to play a move, they would eventually cover the camera, and we can then move to step 2.

If there was no camera covering, but we got a tap, assume we're talking about the player opposite the camera and move to step 3.

**Step 2**

One person just moved their hand over the camera, now check to see if a tap happens within about 5 seconds.

If the camera blocking was a mistake from a cloud, other person, or unidentified flying object, we shouldn't get a tap soon.

Okay, we just got a tap within 5 seconds, so we're pretty sure it's the player on the side of the camera that moved. To make sure, we can add some more advanced logic to our game. That is,

**Step 3**

Throughout the game, every time a tap happens, and we guess which player it is, measure the approximate changes in the accelerometer and gyroscope. Ideally, each player taps with some kind of pattern that we can detect.

Now, when we think we know which player tapped the screen, make some comparisons. If the tap is almost identical to the pattern of the person we think it isn't, switch targeted players. The player near the camera just messed things up.

**Conclusion**

Using this technique, we can pretty closely predict who tapped the screen, and we don't even need any kind of physical comparison. Of course, there are some potential issues, but nothing that even more algorithms couldn't fix.

Basically, you asked if it was possible, and I think it most certainly is.

Comment: Good answer. Are there any sources to look at for doing some of the things, i.e. detecting movement / movement detection algorithms for iOS?

Comment: @Mundi, I'm not sure of any off the top of my head. Though I'm sure there are, I'm the kind of person who likes to write their own algorithms if possible. Are you talking about algorithms related to the accelerometer and gyroscope?

Comment: No, I know about those. I have never tried the video stuff. Not sure how exactly you would monitor significant changes / movements... maybe with captured still images and comparing those somehow?

Comment: @Mundi. Right. My guess is you'd "poll" the images for drastic changes, which I'm sure can be done fairly easily (never tried myself). Since I assume the device is generally laying down, what the camera would normally observe is the ceiling, which of course makes the detection easier.